# strcmp() giving Segmentation fault: 11 and pointer from integer warning

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, avr, strcmp

My problem is that the strcmp() functions makes the following problems:

```
main.c:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

While compiling and the following while running the program:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I know what the errors means, I just don't know any other way to do it...Have thought about using itoa() or sprintf(), but i need the checksum in hex so can't see how I can accomplish that.

The code is as follows:

```
#include "checksum.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char nmea[] ="$GPRMC,131637.000,A,5820.0658,N,00834.5652,E,0.00,,090911,,,A*7E";
    unsigned char checksum[] = "00";
    char data[82];
    int length = strlen(nmea);
    int k = 0;
    int i;
    unsigned char XOR;

    checksum[0] = nmea[(length-2)];
    checksum[1] = nmea[(length-1)];

    for(i=1;i < (length-3);i++){
        data[(i-1)] = nmea[i];
    }
    int dataLength = strlen(data);

    for (XOR = 0, i = 0; i < dataLength; i++)   //XORer for å finne checksum
        XOR ^= (unsigned char)data[i];

    printf("*******************************************************\n");
    printf("Calculating checksum...\n");

    printf("Read checksum: %s\n",checksum);
    printf("Read data: %s\n",data);
    printf("Calculated checksum: %X \n",XOR);

    if(strcmp(XOR,checksum) == 0){          //sammenligner checksumer.
        printf("Checksum: OK!\n");
        //return 1;
    }
    else{
        printf("Checksum: Mismatch!\n");
        //return 0;
    }

    printf("*******************************************************\n");
    //nmeachecksum(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char XOR[2] = { 0, 0 };
```

And then just use `XOR[0]` everywhere.

The above is just my no-segfault rewrite of what your code was *actually* trying to do.

*What it should do* . . . the `strcmp()` is comparing binary text against a formatted version of the same value, so it won't work.  Your `unsigned char XOR;` (or perhaps an 8-bit `<stdint.h>` type) is about right.  But compare this with `==` as a scalar instead of with `strcmp()`.

*What you compare it to* . . . you will need to turn your NMEA printable hex into a scalar operand suitable for `==` so use sscanf() or just open code the hex conversion.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Hex input conversion code examples are available in many stackoverflow answers.</sup>

Comment: Ended up using a hex to integer function found here: http://johnsantic.com/comp/htoi.html and converted the NMEA printable hex. And then I just ran an if test as you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It appears (from a brief look at the code) that you are expecting the correct checksum to be 0.  If so, then just compare against zero:

```
if ( XOR == 0 )
    printf( "OK\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` expects a null terminated C string.  Your `XOR` variable is not even an array.  It's a single `unsigned char` value.  (I'm a bit surprised this even compiles without warning you.)   Anyway, it's preferable to use `memcmp` when comparing binary data.

Answer (score 0):

XOR is a single byte.  Checksum is an array of unsigned characters.  If the compiler let the code through with a warning (*), I'd dump it.

(*): Yes, I know technically this is a "diagnostic".